# How to pass arguments for mac installer

Tags: macos, shell, installation, arguments

I have a pkg (which I created) and I want to install it and pass arguments for the posinstall script, (different from the existing arguments of the pre/post install scripts)
I want to be able to use this arguments  in the postinstall installation script.

I tried to run export ENV_VARIABLE_NAME =ENV_VARIABLE_VALUE, and use env_variable_name in the postinstall script, but when I install the pkg (from the same shell)  -  the postinstall didn't know about ENV_VARIABLE_NAME or its value.
I guess that maybe the installer run in different context? 
so, How can I do it other-way?

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Using `launchctl setenv ENV_VARIABLE_NAME ENV_VARIABLE_VALUE && sudo installer -pkg pkgname.pkg -target /` we can pass arguments to installer.. But not to postinstall